# Is there a really working example which showing the benefits of optimization for Pipeline on x86_64?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, assembly, x86

As known Intel x86_64 processors are superscalar architecture and pipelined architecture.
There is a really working example which showing the benefits of ILP(Instruction-Level Parallelism) for **Superscalar architecture** on x86_64, because there is 4 flows of independent computations. [Is there a really working example which showing the benefits of ILP(Instruction-Level Parallelism) on x86_64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27748020/is-there-a-really-working-example-which-showing-the-benefits-of-ilpinstruction)

But is there a really working example which showing the benefits of ILP(Instruction-Level Parallelism) for **Pipeline architecture** on x86_64?

I.e. is there an example with two asm/C/C++-functions with the same result, but with different implementation and with different performance? Except using: Loop-unrolling, SIMD, Multithreading.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what sort of effect you want to see. On Intel Atom or Pentium 1 you can make a big difference by reordering instructions (to get pairing and/or overlap with subsequent instructions), but for the other microarchs that doesn't do much (it only affects decoding really).

Comment: @harold Yes, I want to see when the manually reordering of instructions better than the automatically reordering in CPU (ROB). On modern Atom, Core-i or Pentium. Or on modern processors it will not give more than 5% of the performance increase?

Comment: On Core-i it doesn't matter as far as I know. Core2 and Pentium M had "favoured decoding patterns", with the 4-1-1 rule and so on (does not apply to short loops, which are supplied by the loop buffer). On an Atom or P1, instruction order is a big deal. So, I can't really show you this effect, unless you have an Atom to test it on.

Comment: I think you have it backwards, my answer on your other question demonstrates pipelining of the floating-point adder. But it doesn't demonstrate superscalar because there is only one floating-point adder. If you want to demonstrate superscalar, just find something that can sustain more than 1 instruction per cycle - which on modern x86 processors, is just about everything that isn't memory bound.

Comment: @Mysticial  Thank you for an interesting remark!  On all Sandy/Ivy Bridge CPUs there are 1 float-point adder (128 Bit FADD) and 4 integer arithmetic units (ALUs on ports 0,1,5,6), isn't it? I.e. your example demonstrates **pipelining of the floating-point adder** with speedup at 3 X times (0.94 sec / 0.31 sec), and harold's example demonstrates **superscalar optimization of the integer adder** with speedup at 3 X times (35.9 ticks / 11.9 ticks). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27748020/is-there-a-really-working-example-which-showing-the-benefits-of-ilpinstruction